# $\inf B = -\sup A$. Please check my proof

Tags: real-analysis

$A \subset \mathbb R$ has an upper bound.
- $B = \{ -a \mid a \in A\}$

prove that $B$ has a lower bound and that $\inf B = -\sup A$.

*I was writing my answer when this question got closed. I posted it again because i wanted someone to check my proof which is as follows.*

In order to understand this true to take some example like consider set A $=(1,2)$ so $B= -A= (-2,-1)$. Now since A has upper bound and also it is subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , so by LUB property it has supremum. Lets call it $s$.

So we have $\forall x\in A , x \leq s$. Multiplying the equality by $-1$, we get $-x > -s $. Also we have $B=-A$. So we have, $\forall x\in -B , -x > -s $. So we have $ \forall -x\in B , -x > -s $. So, clearly B has lower bound which is $s$.

Now to prove that it is the greatest, consider any other lower bound , say $p$, where $p > s$. Now we have $\forall x\in A or -x \in B, -x > p$. So $x <-p.$ So we have $x <-s$. This is contradiction as $x < s$

Comment: In the third paragraph of your proof, the $\le$ was replaced with $<$. We don't lose the equality part when multiplying by -1. Also, I think there is something wrong with the typesetting of the final paragraph: $\forall x \in Aor -x \in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get $\forall x \in A, \;\leq$ that implies $-x\geq-s$, you forgot the equality. **Careful**, this shows $-s$ is a lower bound for $-A$, not $s$.

In the final part the contradiction should be the following:

Let there exist another lower bound for $B=-A$, say $-p$ such that $-p>-s$.

Then, $\forall x \in A, \;-\geq-p$

Note that this implies that $\leq p$ thus $p$ is an upper bound for $A$, by assumption since $-p>-s$, then $p<s$. So $p=sup(A)$ which is a contradiction. Thus $-s=inf(B)=-sup(A)$

Comment: $-x \geq -s$ implies that $-s$ is lower bound for $-x . x \in A$

Comment: Yes, that is exactly that $-s$ is a lower bound for $B$. Since elements in $B$ are $-x$ for $x \in A$

Comment: Then where is the mistake in my proof

Comment: You say $s$ is a lower bound for $B$ which is not true, $-s$ is a lower bound for $B$.